# Differences between QQuickFramebufferObject and QQuickItem?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am working on an application where I want to embed openGL scenes into a QML item.  I want my custom QML items to be driven by C++, [and this article gives an overview of how to do so with a QQuickFramebufferObject.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html)

However, I've noticed that very similar things can be done by simply using a QQuickItem, the distinction seeming to be that QQuickItem has different methods (paint()) compared to the QQuickFrameBufferObject (synchronize(), render(), createFramebufferObject()).

So what are the advantages of one over the other?  Are these compatible?  What is the best way to render a scene with these options?  I've heard that the QQuickFrameBufferObject provides more flexibility with using custom openGL, but that means relatively little to me.

Comment: read http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-scenegraph.html#scene-graph-and-rendering

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed!